# Can a set and its complement have intersection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computational-complexity

My question is really simple.

Can a set $A$ and its complement $\bar{A}$ have intersection? I cannot prove it nor find a counterexample.

**EDIT**

My question is general but it comes to my mind after seeing the well open problem in computational complexity, [*is NP=coNP*?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP). Here NP is the set of all decision problems for which the instances where the answer is "yes" have efficiently verifiable proofs and coNP is its complement. How a set and its complement be equal?

Comment: How do you define the complement?

Comment: Um... by definition....  If foozlenucks are precisely everything that is not a duck, then is it possible for there to be a duck that is a foozlenuck?

Comment: Take an element $x$ from the intersection, is it in A?

Comment: A decision-problem is in coNP iff its complement (as a *problem* not as a *set*) is in NP. So it's prefectly possible to be in both NP and coNP, this just depends on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course they have an intersection. Any two sets have an intersection.

In this case the intersection is the empty set. But that doesn't stop it from *being* the intersection.

---

As for NP and coNP, they are *not complements*. There are problems that are in both NP and coNP -- such as all the decidable ones -- and problems that are in neither, such as the set of true statements of first-order integer arithmetic.

CoNP is the set of decision problems for which the instances where the answer is "no" have efficiently verifiable proofs. A given set is in coNP iff its complement is in NP, but coNP *itself* is not the complement of NP.